# why geth.log too large

Tags: go-ethereum, geth-debugging

geth.log is 84.73GB, so that mobile phone complains no disk space left. Would the geth.log be mandatory to generate?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Geth client doesn't generate log by default, but you could save logs to a file if you want so which isn't really useful I think.

The size of a fast node is already near 130 Gb to be sync with the Ethereum network

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not mandatory to write log, moreover there is no log file by default.